# Alamofire.download by post with parameters not working

Tags: alamofire

Hello I am doing download file by post with parameters. But server can't receive post parameters.
But if i do same thing with get with url parameters. Everything works fine.
Almofire.request also works fine by post with parameters. But only Almofire.download by post with parameter does not work.

Why Alamofire.download does not send paramters by post method ??

```
var sourceStringURL : String = "\(tmp_url)download"
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination =
{
    _, _ in
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: destPath)

    return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
}

Alamofire.download(sourceStringURL, method: .post, parameters: ["id": idStr, "var": varStr], encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil, to: destination)
    .downloadProgress
    {
        progress in

        var tmpPercent : Int = Int(progress.fractionCompleted*100 / 1.0)

    }
    .response
    {
        response in
        if let error = response.error
        {
            print(error)
        }
        else
        {
            //success
        }
    }
```

Server receives post request correctly with Retrofit library in Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found that if i change JSONEncoding.default to URLEncoding.default.
It works fine.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question and answering it too @MomAndDad!!! I have spent so much time addressing the same issue (.GET with nil params work, but the completion block wouldn't even be called if params dictionary was not nil). I wish there was a bounty for this, I'd have give more points (do accept your solution as the answer :)